# Searchi DataGridView Speed up performance C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datagridview, dataview

I have a log viewer that I developped. It uses a Datagridview to display the information. I also added a feature for row filtering using DataView.RowFilter.

```
        DataView dv = new DataView(m_LogFileHandler.Table);
        dv = m_LogFileHandler.Table.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Type {3}({0}) AND Date >= {1} AND Date <= {2} AND Content LIKE '%{4}%'", typeFilter, startDate, endDate, INQuery, textKeywordFilter.Text);
        gridViewLog.DataSource = dv;

        this.gridViewLog.Sort(this.gridViewLog.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

now I wanted to keep the selected row of the Datagridview still selected and focus as long it is valid so I added code to the previous function, here is my entire code look like

```
        string date = "";
        string time = "";
        string type = "";
        string content = "";
        if (gridViewLog.RowCount > 0)
        {
            date = gridViewLog.Rows[gridViewLog.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            time = gridViewLog.Rows[gridViewLog.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            type = gridViewLog.Rows[gridViewLog.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            content = gridViewLog.Rows[gridViewLog.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
        DataView dv = new DataView(m_LogFileHandler.Table);
        dv = m_LogFileHandler.Table.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Type {3}({0}) AND Date >= {1} AND Date <= {2} AND Content LIKE '%{4}%'", typeFilter, startDate, endDate, INQuery, textKeywordFilter.Text);
        gridViewLog.DataSource = dv;

        this.gridViewLog.Sort(this.gridViewLog.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

        DataGridViewRow item = gridViewLog.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == date && r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == time &&
                     r.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == type && r.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == content);
        if (item != null)
        {
            gridViewLog.Rows[item.Index].Selected = true;
            gridViewLog.Rows[item.Index].Cells[0].Selected = true;
        }
}
```

using Stop watch for 70000 records it delayed performance over 2 seconds from 0.05 seconds. is there a way i can code the queering for the selected row better.

Comment: and what seems to be the problem, in regards to 70,000 records and 2 second delay..? perhaps the problem is with your filtering..

Comment: No because when I take the additional code out and I do the same thing I get 0.5 seconds for the 70000 records but adding the search add 2 seconds to the previous performance

Comment: then why not add the search on the database end and have it do it that way.. ?

Comment: Why you sort your rows? You can get rows sorted from database. And maybe you can save selected row before applying filter, then use linq to see if your saved row passed filter: Rows.Where(singleRow=>singleRow==savedRow).FirstOrDefault()!=null

Comment: When you say database is that mean datatables ?? so I'm trying to convert the DataGridView to DataTable use select to get the row I need get it index and use the index to select the DataGridView. what you think